# Action Link mouseover?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover

I am using cshtml/C# and I need images that link as well as have a mouseover effect. I can't seem to find something that works for both.

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Tokyoship_Home_icon.svg/300px-Tokyoship_Home_icon.svg.png" class='img-responsive' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ModelDirectory")'; return false;"/>
```

Is there a solution for this? So on hover, the picture would be http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/512px-Home_Icon.svg.png and on mouseout go back to normal. I have many image links and would rather avoid a jquery function for mouse hover for each image. I'm not sure why `onmouseover="changeImage('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/512px-Home_Icon.svg.png')"` won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've posted a solution with both javaScript and jQuery. You can handle as many images you like.you may check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this works perfectly. Considering I have many different images, I just give them new classes and adjust the hovers via CSS. [Change image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400883/change-image-on-hover)

```
<div class="effect">
<img class="image" src="image.jpg" />
<img class="image hover" src="image-hover.jpg" />
</div>



div.effect img.image{
/*type your css here which you want to use for both*/
}
div:hover.effect img.image{
display:none;
}
div.effect img.hover{
display:none;
}
div:hover.effect img.hover{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: I think this is over-complicating things. You can have just one DIV and change its image background on hover - check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for that. Instead of IMG declare a DIV like that:

```
<div class='img-responsive' onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ModelDirectory")'; return false;">
</div>
```

And use your images as background images in CSS classes. For normal view:

```
div.img-responsive {
    background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Tokyoship_Home_icon.svg/300px-Tokyoship_Home_icon.svg.png');
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

And mouse-hovered view:

```
div.img-responsive:hover {
     background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Home_Icon.svg/512px-Home_Icon.svg.png');
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c3YXN/ Feel free to adjust DIV size in 1st class