# image refers to a link change when user place mouse arrow over image

Tags: html

I have 2 images start.png and start_light.png
I have in html an image refers to a link like this:

```
  <a href="start.php"> <img src="img/start.png"/> </a>
```

All I want is to make "start.png" image to change to "start_light.png" when user place mouse arrow above image start.png

Any idea which is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change image on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400883/change-image-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Css hover class. Set you src attribute to change to start_light.png

Comment: any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

With only HTML and CSS, it is not posible to change the source of image. If you change the `IMG` tag to a `DIV` tag, then you can change the image that is set as the background.

```
div {
    background: url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100/fff');
}
div:hover {
    background: url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100/000001');
}
```

Be aware of the possible SEO and screen reader complications that can arise from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching Google on how to use `:hover` with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<a href="start.php"> <img src="img/start.png"/> </a>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    background:red;
    width:60px;
    height:60px    
}
img:hover{
    background:blue;
}
```

You can also look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lhts/) as an example.

**EDIT**

You may want to include this as your CSS if you want to change the image itself

```
img:hover {
    background:url('img/start_light.png');
}
```