# image change when user places mouse hover link

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a link like this:

```
<a href="start_post_job.php"> <img src="img/post.png"></a>
```

all I want is the image to change to "post_light.png" when user places mouse hover link. Any idea which is the easier way to do this?

Comment: _"Any idea which is the easier way to do this?"_ Out of which options? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pure HTML**

```
<img src="img/post.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/post_light.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/post.png'">
```

Comment: looks great, but when I take mouse over link, I want it to become again the image that it was before. Do I have to add anything else?

Comment: UPDATED: You just needed to add a `onmouseout` event

Comment: ok I have tried it and it looks perfect...

Comment: on final question if you have some free time please. How would you apply your above answer to this php link: echo"<a href='actions.php?action=send&user=$user_id';><img src='img/post.png'/></a> ";

Comment: Infact, the anchor tags around it dont really matter, all that you have to the do is to add the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes to the img tag.

Answer (score 1):

[You have already asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357185/image-refers-to-a-link-change-when-user-place-mouse-arrow-over-image). Please do not ask twice, instead edit your first question if needed.

With only HTML and CSS, it is not posible to change the source of image. If you change the `IMG` tag to a `DIV` tag, then you can change the image that is set as the background.

```
div {
    background: url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100/fff');
}
div:hover {
    background: url('http://www.placehold.it/100x100/000001');
}
```

Be aware of the possible SEO and screen reader complications that can arise from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<a class="switch-image" href="start_post_job.php"> 
    <img class="main-img" src="img/post.png">
    <img class="caption-img" src="img/post-light.png">
</a>
```

The styling:

```
.main-img{
    z-index; // This might not be required
}

.caption-img{
    z-index:10;
    display:none;
}

.swith-image:hover > .caption-img{
    display:inline-block; // either this or block
}

.swith-image:hover > .main-img{
    display:none;
}
```

This should switch the images. Just you play around with it, I think you should beable to do this just by changing the display property of the two or just by changing the z-index.