# Change image when hovering over a list of text

Tags: html, css

Need help on making images change when hovering over a list of text. I've been looking through several examples in here but still can't make it work. Can someone look at my code and figure out what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/8gnkjeze/1/

```
 <section id="about-us" class="page-section light-bg no-pad">
        <div class="container-fluid who-we-are">
            <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-md-6 no-pad text-center">
                    <!-- Image -->

                 <div id="pic" class="pic"></div>                       
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pad-60">                       
                    <div class="section-title text-left">
                        <!-- Title -->
                        <h2 class="title">Industries</h2>
                    </div>

                    <p>We have established a methodical structured approach for the design of service offerings that include maintenance, repair, and on a case-by-case basis overhaul service solutions.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <ul class="arrow-style">

                                <li><div id="word" class="red"><a href="industries.html">Marine Construction</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class="red"><a href="industries.html#offshore-construction">Offshore Construction</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class="red"><a href="industries.html#industrial-construction">Industrial Construction</a></div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <ul class="arrow-style">
                                <li><div class="red"><a href="industries.html#pipe-fabrication">Pipe Fabrication</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class="red"><a href="industries.html#onshore-construction">Onshore Construction</a></div></li>


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

           </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Just to be clear ... when hover each item on the ul the #pic will change the background ??? .... you will need JS

Comment: Can you tell what exactly have you tried? @DaniP it can be done in CSS easily. It's trivial.

Comment: which list of text ?? Do you mean items in <ul class="arrow-style"> ??

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu impossible with the actual markup

Comment: I guess you are using bootstrap, next time to set the example use bootply http://www.bootply.com/DNo24y420z

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400883/change-image-on-hover, since it does essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you cannot traverse up through ancestry with CSS, and your pic holder is that way, you'll need to use a little javascript to handle this.  Here's a simplified example based on the code you provided. This uses jQuery (cause I'm lazy), but can also be accomplished without it using plain ole javascript.

```js
$("ul a").hover(function() {
  $("#pic").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

```css
#pic{
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float:left;
}
#pic.p1 {
  background-image: url("http://fillmurray.com/200/300");
}
#pic.p2 {
  background-image: url("http://fillmurray.com/200/200");
}
#pic.p3 {
  background-image: url("http://fillmurray.com/300/300");
}
#pic.p4 {
  background-image: url("http://fillmurray.com/120/120");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic"></div>                       
     
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" rel="p1">Marine Construction</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="p2">Offshore Construction</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="p3">Pipe Fabrication</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="p4">Onshore Construction</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly i appreciate your help. You made it seem so easy

Comment: Glad to help.  If you find it acceptable please accept the answer, so future users can benefit.